# codeigniter page can not be found issue

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I am working on website on which under the root, i have under construction page. I have upload the files for the new site in folder newsite, which is in the root directory.

I use .htaccess file to remove the index.php from the domain.

If i type www.somesite.com/newsite,  or http://www.somesite.com/newsite welcome controller is displayed. So far, so good.

I have back office administration system, and when i type: 
http://www.somesite.com/newsite/folderName/controllername/functionname i get 404 error.

folderName is the name of the folder in which controllers for the back office are placed. Anyone have any idea why i get this error for the back end only, while the front page is working?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value max_execution_time 6000000
```

If I add index.php in the url for the back office like this
http://www.somesite.com/newsite/index.php/folderName/controllername/functionname

Then the page is displayed.

Regards,Zoran

Comment: perhaps if you could post your relevant .htaccess and routing rules, we might be able to help

Comment: I just edit the post, and i add the code for the .htaccess, but since front page works without the index.php, i doubt that problem lies here. I have default routing rules, and i type the address in the browser but i get 404 error for the back end of the site.

Comment: have you specified this as your base_url http://www.somesite.com/newsite  in config?

Comment: Yes, in the config file i have http://www.somesite.com/newsite. Please, re-read the post, i edited it one min. ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the

`RewriteBase /newsite/` in the `.htaccess`, page is displayed, and now works like a charm.

Comment: Zoran, if this solved your problem, you are encouraged to "accept" it as the correct answer (even if you wrote it).